# Spotipy - entering any kind of username and ask for login informations

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to setup a script that start the spotify playback when choosing this option via a simple menu in the terminal.

The thing is that I want this script to be dynamic, I need to enter a username, and when redirecting on the spotify web autorization page, ask for log in and password and not asking for accepting the python script.

For now I have this code :

```
import sys
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json
import os
import spotipy.util as util
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = 'b0g0000Myclientid000000'
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'b0g0000Myclientsecret000000'
os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] = 'https://google.com/'

# Get the spotify username from the terminal
username = sys.argv[1]
scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state'

try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)
except:
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

# Creation of the spotify object
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

user = sp.current_user()

try:
    devices = sp.devices()
    deviceID = devices['devices'][0]['id']
except:
    print("No devices found...")

print(json.dumps(devices, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
playback = sp.current_user_playing_track()

if playback != None:
    current_artist = playback['item']['artists'][0]['name']
    current_track_name = playback['item']['name']
    print('************** Currently playing : ************** \n Artist:        ' + current_artist + '\n Track name:    ' + current_track_name)
track = sp.search(playback, 1, 0, 'track')
# print(json.dumps(track, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

# For testing purposes : print(json.dumps(playback, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

while True:
    print("\n\nWhat to do ?\n- Play spotify [0]:\n- Play a specific song [1]:\n- Quit [q]")
    menu_answer = input()

    if menu_answer == '0':
        is_playing = playback['is_playing']
        if is_playing == False:
            sp.start_playback()
            print("Started playing the playback (Current song: " + current_track_name + " by " + current_artist + ")")
        else:
            print("Already playing ;)")
    elif menu_answer == '1':
        print("we will play a song")
    elif menu_answer == 'q':
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Help much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be possible to implement the OAuth flow for authorizing users without displaying to them the screen for them to authorize your script. This needs to be done for any new user.

However you can save the credentials for users, and use those to get the authorization details for someone who has already authorized your script.

E.g.

1. User enters username and you don't have any saved credentials, so you display the authorization screen and they accept. You get the authorization code and refresh code and save them somewhere, associated with the User's ID.
2. When the user enters username and you have the credentials saved, you don't need to display the authorization screen as they've already authorized your script. You can straight away display your menu with options for them to control playback.

Let me know if I misunderstood the question at all.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay.

i've seen after using mutliple account that I was totally stupid because we cannot access an account from another so what I was trying to do was pointless. Spotipy detect what account is logged on the machine and if we're not logged on spotify, before autorizing the app it prompt us to enter our username and password.